# Need help getting scroll up event

Tags: python, events, scroll, pygame, mouseevent

I'm creating a program in Python using Pygame and I can't find a working method to detect when I scroll up.

I'm trying to recreate a popular video called "Interstellar Mouse"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aANF2OOVX40

I'm trying to get it to play the same music when you scroll (to do the same thing without having to edit it in).

I've been able to get this to work with keypresses by doing something like this:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[pygame.K_KEYNAME]:
     pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
```

Just using keys seems to work fine but I need to use the mouse wheel.

This is the main loop:

```
run = True

while run:
    #quit game after pressing the close button
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    #exit game by pressing ESC
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        run = False

    #scroll to activate
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 4:
                pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
            else:
                pygame.music.pause()


    #update background
    win.blit(bg, (width / 4, height / 4))
    pygame.display.update()



pygame.quit()
```

The results are very inconsistent. Sometimes if I scroll really fast it will start playing after about a second but never stop. Sometimes it just doesn't play at all.

Comment: Could `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` work?

Answer (score 0):

This part here:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.button == 4:
            pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        else:
            pygame.music.pause()
```

Every time you have `event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` you are either pausing or unpausing the music.   Mouse clicks and scroll downs will pause your music.  I would change this to a specific pause option, say `if event.button == 2` instead of your `else` for better control.